# How to sum a table of numbers in Lua?

Tags: lua, sum, built-in

Does Lua have a builtin `sum()` function? I can't seem to find one, and I've looked almost everywhere in the documentation. Maybe `table.sum()`, or something of the like, to follow the current conventions. But since I couldn't find it, I had to implement it:

```
function sum(t)
    local sum = 0
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        sum = sum + v
    end

    return sum
end
```

It seems kind of funny to have to implement something this simple, though. Does a builtin function exist, or no?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I disagree, it would be redundant to have something that primitive and specific as `table.sum` in the standard library.

It'd be more useful to implement `table.reduce` along the lines of:

```
---Reduces an array
---@param list any[] An array
---@param fn function The reduction predicate
---@param init any The initial accumulator value
---@return any The final value of the accumulator
table.reduce = function (list, fn, init)
    local acc = init
    for k, v in ipairs(list) do
        if 1 == k and not init then
            acc = v
        else
            acc = fn(acc, v)
        end
    end
    return acc
end
```

And use it with a simple lambda:

```
table.reduce(
    {1, 2, 3},
    function (a, b)
        return a + b
    end,
    0
)
```

The example implementation of `reduce` lacks type-checking but you should get the idea.

Comment: I disagree, something as commonly used as `sum` should be in the std-lib. Writing lambdas gets old quick -- it's not about difficulty of composition but readibility of the code. When reading hundreds - thousands lines of codes, I'd much  rather read `my_table.sum` than your bloated blob.

Comment: The point is, `reduce` is generic and useful for many applications. A little verbosity in specific cases is OK, if you want the standard library to be minimal as it is in Lua.

Comment: I just feel the need to point out that `reduce` isn't in the std-lib either...

Comment: So as many, many other commonplace functions. Lua is not a general-purpose language like Python. If you need at least some batteries, you can try Penlight package.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ipairs` used in the solution works only on tables with integer keys, if you have `{"a" = 1, "b" = 2}`. The solution won't work. You'll need an additional counter var.