# Why is this function to add the contents of a table together in Lua returning nothing

Tags: lua, sum, lua-table

I am stuck trying to make the contese of a table (all integers) add together to form one sum. I am working on a project where the end goal is a percentage. I am putting the various quantities and storing them in one table. I want to then add all of those integers in the table together to get a sum. I haven't been able to find anything in the standard Library, so I have been tyring to use this:

```
function sum(t)
local sum = 0
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    sum = sum + v
end

return sum
```

However, its not giving me anything after return sum.... Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `end` in missing (to close the function definition) after `return sum`.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution to this problem of reducing the contents of a table (in this case by summing the elements) is [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8695525/6286781) (warning: no type checking in code sketch).

If your function is not returning at all, it is probably because you are missing an `end` statement in the function definition.

If your function is returning zero, it is possible that there is a problem with the table you are passing as an argument.  In other words, the parameter `t` may be `nil` or an empty table.  In that case, the function would return zero, the value to which your `local sum` is initialized.

If you add `print (k,v)` in the loop for debugging, you can determine whether the function has anything to add.  So I would try:

```
local function sum ( t ) do
   print( "t", t ) -- for debugging: should not be nil
   local s = 0
   for k,v in pairs( t ) do
        print(k,v) --for debugging
        s = s + v
   end
   return s
end
local myTestData = { 1, 2, 4, 9 }
print( sum( myTestData) )
```

The expected output when running this code is

```
t   table: [some index]
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   9
16
```

Notice that I've changed the variable name inside the function from `sum` to `s`. It's preferable not to use the function name `sum` as the variable holding the sum in the function definition. The `local sum` in the function overrides the global one, so for example, you couldn't call `sum()` recursively (i.e. call `sum()` in the definition of `sum()`).